# Does the Intel HD Graphics 520 iGPU support HDMI 2.0?

Tags: display

Does my Lenovo Ideapad 510-15isk support HDMI 2.0? I'm trying to connect my new 1440p monitor to my laptop, I'm using a Sven HDMI 2.0 cable, maybe it's faulty, I can't find anywhere about if the card even supports HDMI 2.0.

Edit: Should I buy a DP to HDMI adapter maybe?
Edit2: I can get full 1440p resolution, but only at 50hz.
Edit3: The discrete card is a Geforce 940MX 4GB, should I connect to it instead?

Answer (score 1):

Probably not via HDMI, nowhere is the HDMI standard listed specifically, but whether this device actually supports HDMI 2.0 or not really relevant...

For the Lenovo Ideapad 510 platform, the maximum resolution for an external monitor via HDMI is 1920x1080@60hz according to the Lenovo Product Specification Reference. You're attempting to exceed what the computer's design is capable of by connecting a 1440p display.

That said, from the given information we can assume it is likely equipped wiuth an HDMI 1.2a port because the maximum resolution is 1920x1080@60Hz, which would match that spec.

Reference: [Lenovo IdeaPad 510 (15") Platform Specifications](https://psref.lenovo.com/Product/Lenovo_Laptops/ideapad_510_15)

Note at the bottom of the Graphics section:

> Max resolution: 1920x1080@60Hz (HDMI); 1920x1200@60Hz (VGA)

If you have the capability of connecting it to a Display Port interface, and get a sufficient quality adapter to convert it to HDMI, you should be able to get it to work though.